# seting XML indentation in the XML R library

Tags: xml, r

I am creating an xml file with the [XML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) package. By default, the function `saveXML` indents **1** space for each nested element.

Is there a way to set this number of spaces to a different one and indent for instance 4 spaces more for each level?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `saveXML` is a character string so split it at newlines and then if there are n leading spaces replace them with n * indent leading spaces.  Using the example in `?saveXML`

```
library(XML)
library(gsubfn) 

xmlFormat <- function(doc, indent = 3) {
   s <- strsplit(saveXML(doc), "\n")[[1]]
   g <- gsubfn("^( +)", x ~ sprintf("%*s", indent * nchar(x), " "), s)
   paste(g, collapse = "\n")
}

# test

f <- system.file("exampleData", "test1.xml", package = "XML")
doc <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(f))

cat(xmlFormat(doc), "\n")
```

giving:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
   <a>Some text &lt; 3&gt;.</a>
   <b>More text &gt; 3</b>
</test>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. And nice library `gsubfn` which I did not know jet.